Why does Frame LinearGradientBrush not respect StartPoint and EndPoint with values other than 0 and 1
I am attempting to create a frame which has a linear gradient going from yellow to green. I would like the top-right corner to be yellow, and the middle of the bottom to be green.
I am using the following XAML:
 <Frame Padding="0" BorderColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="200" Margin="10">
     <Frame.Background>
         <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
             <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
                       Offset="0.0" />
             <GradientStop Color="Green"
                       Offset="1.0" />
         </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Frame.Background>

 </Frame>

Here is what I see when I run the application:

My expectation is that I would see something similar to this (red arrow added to help visualize the start and end of the gradient):

I notice that if I change the EndPoint X to 0, it works as expected:
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">


I have tried values of 0.5 and .5 but neither seem to work, they all result in the yellow starting at the left side of the frame. I am using MAUI 8.0.7.

You may try using a Border instead of a Frame, If you're building a new .NET MAUI app.

You set the right Startpoint and Endpoint. You can chenge the Offset of the color green to "0.5".
<Frame Padding="0" BorderColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="200" Margin="10">
    <Frame.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow"
           Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Green"
           Offset="0.5" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Frame.Background>

</Frame>


I'm sorry but I don't think this answers the original question. Changing the offset of the color green to 0.5 will make the green not show up, but it will not be the same as having the endpoint at (1,0.5). Also, it doesn't answer the question of why fractional endpoints seem to be broken.

You can see StartPoint="1,0" means that the yellow color start from the top-right corner of the area being painted. It should not appear the first picture situation you post.

You can check if you set the diagonal linear gradient.
